# Why do Resharper / Jetbrains [NotNull] annotated interfaces warn me of nullreferenceexceptions?

Tags: c#, annotations, resharper

I am trying to go through my project and annotate all my methods with respective Resharper / Jetbrains annotations so I have a little help and something to punch me when I accidently try to pass stuff which does not belong somewhere.

However, this is something I just can't understand.

Consider the following:

```
public interface ITestClass
{
    Task<int?> TestMethod([CanBeNull] int? testInput);
}

public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    public async Task<int?> TestMethod(int? testInput)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(testInput);
    }
}

public class TestConsumer
{
    [NotNull]
    private readonly ITestClass m_tester;

    [NotNull]
    private readonly TestClass m_tester2;

    public TestConsumer([NotNull] ITestClass tester, [NotNull] TestClass tester2)
    {
        m_tester = tester;
        m_tester2 = tester2;
    }

    public async Task TestMethod([NotNull] int? testInput)
    {
        var test1 = await m_tester.TestMethod(testInput);
        var test2 = await m_tester2.TestMethod(testInput);
    }
}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I rebuilt this in order to show a problem I am facing right now. Usually, I am using dependency injection and I expect interfaces of certain services (let 'ITestClass' be the interface of a service 'TestClass' in thsi case) in the constructor of my e.g. controller (see 'TestConsumer').

However, R# / Jetbrains Annotations apparently don't like this. However, when I try it with the implementation of that interface instead - No problemo.

This is really a bit annoying. I don't want to have my whole code wiggled now. Apparently this also is only a problem when dealing with await / async code, as this works for both cases if I leave out the 'await' for example, but that is not an option.

Is there any solution? In the end, what could R# possibly be missing in the interface which it has in the implementation instead? The method definition is there.

EDIT:

For additional information:

I am running Resharper Ultimate 2018.3.1 in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.6.1.

Comment: Could we get the code posted directly instead of a picture?

Comment: This doesn't repro for me (with R# 2016.1.2) so perhaps there's a setting to turn it off?

Comment: In future, you may wish to edit the original post - so as not to lose the comments etc from the original.

Comment: @JonathonChase Someone was already so kind do that that. Thanks, whoever was at work here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementation (TestClass.TestMethod) is an async method which returns instance of Task and never returns null. Signature of interface method "ITestClass.TestMethod" does not guarantee the result is not null (you can implement it with non-async method that simply returns null). So in "pessimistic" analysis mode ReSharper assumes that "ITestClass.TestMethod" can return null. To fix it you can add "NotNull" annotation to the interface's method:

```
public interface ITestClass
{
    [NotNull] Task<int?> TestMethod([CanBeNull] int? testInput);
}
```

Comment: Good solution! I was under the impression that I have to annotate methods with a return type of e.g. Task<T> with [ItemNotNull] so R# does evaluate the content of the Task returned.

Comment: [ItemNotNull] on a method that returns Task<T> tells to ReSharper about nullability of the task's result